# If ID exists, delete before insert to avoid duplication (C# / ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using the code below to insert records into a SQL Server table. The code works perfectly, but the part I need to add is a check to make sure that the ID passed does not exist before inserting it. If records with the passed ID exists, those records need to be deleted, and then inserted again.

Would it be possible to ask for help to figure out the part that would check the ID before the insert?

I will continue to try to figure it out on my own, but I hope someone could offer some help if possible.

Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult InsertData(List<Meeting> meeting)
{
    bool status = false;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (MeetingEntities db = new MeetingEntities())
        {
            foreach (var i in meeting)
            {
                db.Meeting.Add(i);
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            status = true;
        }
    }

    return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
}
```

[image: Table Definition]

Thank you,

Erasmo

Comment: Is meeting.ID the primary key for your table? If yes then you can simply call meeting.Find(i.ID) before adding the item

Comment: Hello @Steve - MeetingID and AgendaItem are the primary key of the table. I did not created the table nor have decision power to change its definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it against our meeting list before adding to the context object like

```
            using (MeetingEntities db = new MeetingEntities())
            {
                foreach (var i in meeting)
                {
                    if(!meeting.Any(x => x.ID == i.ID)) {
                    db.Meeting.Add(i);
                   }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
```

You said * I need to check and if exists delete those records with that MeetingId* .. then you can do something like below

```
var meetingIds = meeting.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
db.Meeting.Where(x => meetingIds.Contains(x.ID))
               .ToList().ForEach(db.Meeting.DeleteObject);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Well you can combine of this operations

```
            using (MeetingEntities db = new MeetingEntities())
            {
                //insert operation
                foreach (var i in meeting)
                {
                    if(!meeting.Any(x => x.ID == i.ID)) {
                    db.Meeting.Add(i);
                   }
                }

                //Delete Operation
              var meetingIds = meeting.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();
              db.Meeting.Where(x => meetingIds.Contains(x.ID))
               .ToList().ForEach(db.Meeting.DeleteObject);

                // Save the changes
                db.SaveChanges();
                status = true;
            }
```

Comment: Hello @Rahul - Thank you for your suggested answer, I need to check and if exists delete those records with that MeetingId, the reason is that if a MeetingID is attempted to be re-inserted is due to some changes/edits that the other columns might contain. Thank you

Comment: Thank you @Rahul - I am not sure how to put all the code together, that is the first part you add and then the update. How will it look all together? Sorry for the bothering.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to check if is already present if not insert it.. like:

```
public ActionResult InsertData(List<Meeting> meeting)
        {
            bool status = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (MeetingEntities db = new MeetingEntities())
                {

                    foreach (var i in meeting)
                    {
                        if(db.Meeting.FirstOrDefault(xx=>xx. ID == i. ID) == null)
                        {
                         db.Meeting.Add(i);
                        }

                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    status = true;
                }
            }
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { status = status } };
        }
```

Comment: Hello @federico scamuzzi - Thank you for your suggested answer, I need to check and if exists delete those records with that MeetingId, the reason is that if a MeetingID is attempted to be re-inserted is due to some changes/edits that the other columns might contain. Thank you.

Comment: ok ... so have you archived alsonthe delete? ..or do you need i update the answer?